# Windows Media Player 12 thinks tracks from the same album are from separate albums

Tags: windows-media-player

I'm running Windows Media Player 12 on Windows 7 Home Premium.

I was listening to an Ian Brown album which I didn't have artwork for so I right clicked and selected "Update album details" and it proceeded to split the tracks up into 3 separate albums.  Yet all 3 new albums still have the same album title.

Does anybody know how to fix this error to get all 12 tracks back into 1 album again?

Answer (score 6):

This issue could, as njd says, be related to undisplayed characters. However I've found issues with conflicting album artists and album covers to cause things like this (particularly why I don't use WMP anymore).

To fix this is simple: just drag the album cover onto another to merge them. Any conflicting details will be fixed and they will appear under the same album.

[image]

Comment: Just a note, if you have an album with different artists on it and you drag and drop it will change the artist to whoever you dropped it on.

Comment: oh that's good to note, but is that for Artist or Album Artist?

Comment: Sometimes this still won't merge them, if you don't have the same file type for every track. In this case you should be able to drag them together again, and you'll get a prompt asking if you want to disable albums from being separated by file type.

Answer (score 1):

The details update probably gave some (specific) detail about some of the tracks, but not the others. Probably something like "Year" or "Composer" that you wouldn't see on the file view. You need to edit (some of) the tracks so that WMP knows that they are from the same album.

Unfortunately, it seems that WMP has removed it's advanced tag editor in version 12. I can't find it anywhere at least. If jay's drag and drop method doesn't work (maybe that is for album name only), and if you can't find a built-in tag editor (or maybe a plug in?) then you'll need a third party option. I used [Mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) for this purpose and stuck with it as my main audio player. It has a very strong and easy to use tag editor, and an auto-tag feature which should avoid these WMP issues.

Comment: Yes, apparently the tag editor has been removed in version 12, you can only edit what the player displays.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem but I found that if you go to 'Album' view and right click -'update album info' it will consolidate the album. Not sure if it always works or if it 'sticks'. We'll see...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions.  However, when I've gone into the player this morning to try some of them out the problem has automatically sorted itself out anyway and all the tracks are now listed under 1 album again.

Not sure what to make of this, maybe the player automatically checks for stuff like this or it's another bug or something.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If these solutions don't seem to work, don't forget:

**Alt+T > "Apply media information changes"**

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was the tags.
You need Album Artist to be "Various" and then have the track artist listed under Contributing Artist.
Fixed mine in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**Editing metadata of audio files in Windows Media Player to consolidate**

In Media Player Click on “Music” – third item on far left (just below Playlist).
Toggle menu on the far right to choose "details" (just to the left of Search box).
You can add or remove columns (right click on title bar).
Sort by Album name.
Under "Album Artist" column, right click on item to edit.  Change to e.g “Various” (as specified in earlier answer by Matt).
Using CTRL  or Shift you can highlight all the rows in the album, then edit one  cell to change all highlighted in  that column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lVNq.png)

Alternatively, with **Windows Explorer**, highlight one or more files, right click and select Properties. Select the Details tab.  Click on Album Artist field and enter new text.